# AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The values in where clause must not be object or array

Tags: model, assert, knex.js

I'm testing my Cars model, and in one of the tests I have to pass in a 'carPlate' value to search for.

This is the method I have connected to knex from my Cars constructor, and I pass in params like so.

`models/Cars.js`

```
  /**
   * search active car model
   * @param {Object} parameters of the search
   *   - fbUserId
   *   - carPlate
   * @return {Promise<Array<Cars>} car object
   */
  search(params = {}) {
    let self = this

    params.limit = (params.limit) ? params.limit : 20
    params.offset = (params.offset) ? params.offset : 0

    const { limit, offset, ...rest } = params 

    let raw = self.knex.select().table(tableName).where(rest).limit(limit).offset(offset).toSQL()
    return self.knex.raw(raw.sql, raw.bindings).then((result) => {
      return  result[0]
    })
  }
```

However I get the assertion error in the title, and I've looked up passing objects in where condition and it's absolutely plausible so I'm wondering why it's not working, or if I understood the error wrong.

`tests/models/Cars.js`

```
 it('should be able to insert car', () => {

    const newCar = {
      "fbUserId":"fbUserId12232223",
      "carPlate":"A38232DB",
      "carInfo" : {
        "model":"Honda",
        "year":2022
      }
    }

    return mCar.post({
      ...newCar
    }).then((result) => {
      assert.isDefined(_insert1.id,'inserted car should have an id')
      assert.equal(_insert1.fbUserId,result.fbUserId,'inserted car fbUserId match')
      assert.equal(_insert1.carPlate,result.carPlate,'inserted car carplate match'),
      assert.deepEqual(_insert1.carInfo,result.carInfo,'inserted car carinfo should match')

      _insert1 = result
    })
  })
```

I have a test to post a new car first, then search for its carPlate and assert the results.

```
 it('should be able to search car by carplate only', () => {
    const carPlate = _insert1.carPlate

    return mCar.search({carPlate}).then((result)=>{
      assert.isDefined(result.carPlate,'returned car should have carPlate')
      // assert.equal(result.carPlate,carPlate,'returned car carPlate should match')
    })
  })
```